# Distance of a function (as a vector) from a certain kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, projection

Consider $C[-1,1]$, the normed linear space of real-valued continuous functions on $[-1,1]$ with the supremum norm. Let K be the kernel of the linear functional $I: f \to \int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx $ on
$C[-1,1]$. What is the distance of the function $f(x)=x^2$ from $K$?

Clearly, $f(x)=x^2$ is not in the kernel $K$, and so the distance has to be non-zero. Also, the orthogonal projection formula doesn't seem to work here because the kernel is infinite dimensional.
I am stumped. How do I even begin to attack this problem?

Comment: On first glance I'd say, that $g(x) = x^2-\frac{1}{3} \in \ker I$ should minimize the distance since it has constant pointwise-distance to $f$ and it definitely is a local minimum

Comment: @StiftungWarentest Thanks! You are right about the answer! +1 for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, @StiftungWarentest is right, the distance is $d(f,K) = \frac13$ and $g(x) = x^2-\frac{1}{3}$ is the distance minimizer.

First we can find the distance minimizer in the $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm. Namely, then $K^\perp$ is the space of constant functions whose orthonormal basis is $\left\{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right\}$ so the orthogonal projection of $f$ onto $K$ is given by
$$P_K f = (I-P_{K^\perp })f = f - \left\langle f, \frac1{\sqrt{2}}\right\rangle \frac1{\sqrt{2}} = f - \frac12 \int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,dx$$
which indeed turns out to be equal to $g$.  Since $\|\cdot\|_2 \le \sqrt{2}\|\cdot\|_\infty$ for all $h\in K$ we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} = \left\|\frac13\right\|_2=\|f-g\|_2 \le \|f-h\|_2 \le \sqrt{2}\|f-h\|_\infty$$
and therefore $\|f-h\|_\infty \ge \frac13$. On the other hand, we have $\|f-g\|_\infty = \left\|\frac13\right\|_\infty = \frac13$ so we conclude that $d(f,K) = \frac13$.

Comment: I have a question though. How do you know "at first glance" that $g(x)=x^2−1/3∈kerF$ is the minimiser?

Comment: @krishna2016 If you are asking how StiftungWarentest noticed that this is the minimizer, I have no idea. I calculated the orthogonal projection of $f$ onto $K$ and then concluded that this projection had to be the mimimizer for the $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm and then by chance it turned out to be the mimimizer for the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$-norm as well. I don't have any deeper insight than this.

Comment: I guess I should fire the question at him then. Thanks anyway for responding. I will reach out if I get thrown by anything here.

Comment: @krishna2016 it was a very unspectacular and handwaivy argument that led me to this assumption: Assume there was a minimizer $g$ s.t. $|f(x)-g(x)|$ was **not** constant, then we could find $x_{min}, x_{max}$ which minimize/maximize that distance and it would hold that $||f-g||_\infty = |f(x_{max})-g(x_{max})|$. But one could easily "shift simultaneously both $g(x_{max})$ and $g(x_{min})$ towards $f$" in a manner that keeps $g$ continuous and the integral constant. This would however decrease $|f(x_{max})-g(x_{max})| = ||f-g||_\infty$ which contradicts $g$ having already been a minimizer.

Comment: @StiftungWarentest Plus one for your handwaivy argument. Very crisp.